# On page load add class to dynamic generated element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add a class to an element that is dynamically added to the page. I have seen a lot of solutions for on click or other events, I can't seem to find one for on page load. I need my code to fire right away(without a user triggered event) once the elemnt is added to the page. Is there an equivalent to the following code, just not for click but page load:

```
$('body').on('click', '#myDiv', function() {
    $(this).addClass('myClass');
});
```

Comment: any advice on why im getting down voted? thought its a pretty straight forward question.

Comment: If you want to do something once it is added in `DOM`, why do you have `click` event as well ?

Comment: Because I want the event to happen right when the page loads, I want this to happen without the user interaction.

Comment: Event is attached for the `element`, how will it invoke if element is not there in DOM ?

Comment: The element I am trying to target is dynamically added to the DOM via a source I have no access to. To manipulate it ( add class ) I had to first target a parent element that is not dynamic. Then I could use .bind to target its child (the dynamic element). From there I could add the class to it. I answered the question below.

Comment: So what is the question ? Check out my deleted answer..It may help you..

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("body").bind("DOMNodeInserted", function() {
    $(this).find('#myDiv').addClass('my_own_class');
 my});
```

Because dynamical added elements via JavaScript can't be directly accessed and the element I am trying to target is dynamically added to the DOM via a source I have no access to. To manipulate it ( add class ) I had to first target a parent element that is not dynamic. Then I could use .bind to target its child (the dynamic element). From there I could add the class to it. I answered the question below.

Comment: An explanation as to what the code does would benefit others in the community looking for similar solutions

Comment: This works - but you may want to edit out the last stray "my" in your snippet...my});

Answer (score -2):

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

> A function to execute after the DOM is ready. [jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @neal you got any advice for me?